# Having problems while writing a .CSV file in Java?

Tags: python, java, pandas, csv, file

So, I'm trying to realize a program that downloads all the Issues from a GitHub repository and stores their IDs and their Bodies into a .CSV file.
This is what I wrote and kinda works (it downloads the issues):

```
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("ISSUE-DOWNLOAD.csv");
        writer.append("Id \t Body Text");
        writer.append("\n");

        for (GHIssue issue : repository.getIssues(stateOpen)) {
            String body = issue.getBody(); 
            if( body!=null ) 
            {   
                writer.append(issue.getNumber() + "\t");
                writer.append(body + "\t");
            }
            writer.append("\n");
        }
```

[The problem is that I'm not truly creating a .CSV file where a every row has an ID and a BODY in two columns, but I'm creating a file that puts the body wherever.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pNPS.png)

I think that the problem might be the MarkDown language of GitHub issues and the fact that excel may not read non UTF-8 characters.
The CSV is full of "???????" indeed.
And if I try reading the file through Python, I get UTF-8 DECODING ERRORS:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('ISSUE-DOWNLOAD.csv', sep='\t', na_values='n/a')
```

File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 642, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 73222: invalid start byte

Does anybody know how can I handle this?
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: First of all, that's not a CSV file, it's a TSV file. What are the invalid characters? What is the code point of, say, the first invalid character?

Comment: What if the values you're writing contain tabs? You make no effort to escape them. This is why you should use a well-debugged library for reading or writing CSV and TSV files.

Comment: I deleted every \n and \t from the body both via Java and via Excel and it still doesn't work

Comment: And what's the problem about it being a TSV? I told excel to separate values for \t and not commas

Comment: The problem is you called it a CSV. A CSV is not a TSV.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values

Comment: Ok thanks! Anyway I was using \t because there were no tabs in any body's fields but there were many commas everywhere (and removing them didnt work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use your custom parser or writer for a non-trivial format. Use an API like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then, create with your required config (e.g. the default)

```
try (CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(new FileWriter("/tmp/uster_issues.csv"), CSVFormat.DEFAULT)) {
    printer.printRecord("number", "title", "createdAt", "body");
    for (GHIssue issue : repository.getIssues(GHIssueState.ALL))
        printer.printRecord(issue.getNumber(), issue.getTitle(), issue.getCreatedAt(), issue.getBody());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can open the file **setting the right CSV import options** for example using LibreOffice

[image]

with your expected result

[image]

all fields (numbers, strings, dates and long string like `body`) have been imported.

Comment: It's great to hear that, would you be so kind as to rate my answer? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use a `CSVWriter`.
You can use the one offered in `apache commons` for example.

Add it in your pom if you are using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or gradle

```
compile "org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.9.0"
```

Then you can do something like the following

```java
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("./ISSUED_DONWLOAD.csv"));
CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("issueNumber", "issueBody").withDelimiter(' '));

for (GHIssue issue : repository.getIssues(stateOpen)) {
            String body = issue.getBody(); 
            if( body!=null ) 
            {   
                csvPrinter.printRecord(issue.getNumber, body);
            }
        }
csvPrinter.flush();
```

In my example this creates a file in the same directory that looks like

```
issueNumber issueBody
1234 bodyOfTheIssue
7231 bodyOfAnotherIssue
```

Comment: with printer.printRecord you mean your csvPrinter right?
And why did you leave the "delimiter" blank? Shouldn't I put \t or comma?

Comment: @eed yes that is correct, by printer i mean csvPrinter, and the deimeter is set to space, you can set it however you like.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again :) Both your advices worked fine!

Comment: @eed make sure to mark the solution as an answer so other people can benefit from it :)